# Remove foreach loop with the help of linq

Tags: c#

I have some problem with my code. I want to replace the `ForEach` loop with the help of `LINQ` here, is there any way or solution to solve my problem? My code is given bellow.

```
static public string table2Json(DataSet ds, int table_no)
{
    try
    {
        object[][] tb = new object[ds.Tables[table_no].Rows.Count][];
        int r = 0;

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[table_no].Rows)
        {
            tb[r] = new object[ds.Tables[table_no].Columns.Count];
            int col = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn column in ds.Tables[table_no].Columns)
            {
                tb[r][col] = dr[col];
                if ((tb[r][col]).Equals(System.DBNull.Value))
                {
                    tb[r][col] = "";
                }
                col++;
            }
            r++;
        }
        string table = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tb, Formatting.Indented);
        return table;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tools.log(ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ queries, it doesn't modify anything. What is this code supposed to do? Extract a DataTable's data into a jagged array instead of a 2D array? Just to convert it to JSON? Why?

Comment: JSON.NET can already handle DataTable instances. Table columns aren't just array columns either and their name, type matters. Serializing each row as an object with named fields is far better than serializing them as an unstructured `object[]` array

Comment: Use `throw;` instead of `throw ex;` to preserve the stacktrace.

Comment: it should be  "public static string" instead of "static public string" in front of your function name

Answer (score 0):

This question really asks 3 different things:

- how to serialize a DataTable
- how to change the DataTable serialization format and finally
- how to replace nulls with empty strings, even though an empty string isn't a NULL.

JSON.NET already handles DataSet and DataTable instance serialization with a DataTableConverter whose source can be found [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/DataTableConverter.cs). You could just write :

```
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Given this DataTable :

```
var dataTable=new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("SurName",typeof(string));
dataTable.Rows.Add("Moo",null);
dataTable.Rows.Add("AAA","BBB");
```

You get :

```
[{"Name":"Moo","SurName":null},{"Name":"AAA","SurName":"BBB"}]
```

DataTables aren't 2D arrays and the column names and types *matter*. Generating a separate row object with named fields is far better than generating an `object[]` array. It also allows makes it far easier for clients to handle the JSON string without knowing its schema in advance. With an `object[]` for each row, the clients will have to know what's stored in each location in advance.

If you want to use a different serialization format, you could customize the DataTableConverter. Another option though, is to use [DataRow.ItemArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.itemarray?view=netframework-4.8) to get the values as an `object[]` and LINQ to get the rows, eg :

```
object[][] values=dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                           .Select(row=>row.ItemArray)
                           .ToArray();
```

Serializing this produces :

```
[["Moo",null],["AAA","BBB"]]
```

And there's no way to tell which item is the name and which is the surname any more.

Replacing DBNulls with strings in this last form needs an extra `Select()` to replace DBNull.Value with `""` :

```
object[][] values=dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                           .Select(row=>row.ItemArray
                                           .Select(x=>x==DBNull.Value?"":x)
                                           .ToArray())
                           .ToArray();
```

Serializing this produces :

```
[["Moo",""],["AAA","BBB"]]
```

That's what was asked, but now *we have no way to tell whether the Surname is an empty string, or just doesn't exist*.

This may sound strange, but Arabic names may be one long name without surname. Makes things interesting for airlines or travel agents that try to issue tickets (ask me how I know).

We can get rid of `ToArray()` if we use `var` :

```
var values=dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                         .Select(row=>row.ItemArray
                                         .Select(x=>x==DBNull.Value?"":x));
```

JSON serialization will work the same.

Comment: @Sanjaygautam I already posted the full code. You don't need anything more, just retrieve the DataTable and write the query

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not a nice fit for this sort of thing because you are using explicit indexes `r` and `col` into multiple "array structures" (and there is no easy/tidy way to achieve multiple, parallel enumeration).

**Other issues**

1. `tb` is repeatedly `new`ed, filled with data and then replaced in the next iteration, so you end up capturing only the last row of input to the JSON string - that's a logical bug and won't work as I think you intend.
2. The inner `foreach` loop declares but does not use the iteration variable `column` - that's not going to break anything but it is redundant.

You will get more mileage out of using JSON.Net properly (or coding the `foreach` loops as `for` loops instead if you want to navigate the structures yourself).